# mvn appengine:run - error 403 (spring boot web with jsp)

Tags: spring, jsp, google-app-engine

I got 403, 404 error when running with gg AppEngine

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: WARNING: Your working directory, (E:\Eclipse Projects\ysuria) is not equal to your
[INFO] GCLOUD: web application root (E:\Eclipse Projects\ysuria\target\ysuria-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
[INFO] GCLOUD: You will not be able to access files from your working directory on the production server.
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-03-20 11:18:50.595:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.18.v20170406
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-03-20 11:18:57.362:WARN:oeja.ClassInheritanceHandler:qtp328638398-16:
[INFO] GCLOUD: java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ClassInheritanceHandler.addToInheritanceMap(ClassInheritanceHandler.java:72)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ClassInheritanceHandler.handle(ClassInheritanceHandler.java:58)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser$MyClassVisitor.visit(AnnotationParser.java:476)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:650)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:525)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:978)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:958)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:902)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:851)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:546)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

here is my code https://github.com/NhuY97/ysuria
thanks

Comment: Please add the code which is causing this error

Comment: https://github.com/NhuY97/ysuria

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot web application running on Google App Engine - throws jetty exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492583/spring-boot-web-application-running-on-google-app-engine-throws-jetty-exceptio)